# Observation in Row to Column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has all observations in one column and looks like this;

```
   [1] "1"
   [2] "201"                                                       
   [3] " van Aert WoutTeam Jumbo-Visma "                           
   [4] "25"                                                        
   [5] "Team Jumbo-Visma"                                          
   [6] "300"                                                       
   [7] "200"                                                       
   [8] "4:58:564:58:56"                                            
   [9] "2"                                                         
  [10] "234"                                                       
  [11] "  Formolo DavideUAE-Team Emirates "                        
  [12] "27"                                                        
  [13] "UAE-Team Emirates"                                         
  [14] "250"                                                       
  [15] "150"                                                       
  [16] "0:300:30"                                                  
  [17] "3"                                                         
  [18] "87"                                                        
  [19] "  Schachmann MaximilianBORA - hansgrohe "                  
  [20] "26"                                                        
  [21] "BORA - hansgrohe"                                          
  [22] "215"                                                       
  [23] "120"                                                       
  [24] "0:320:32"                                                  
  [25] "4"                                                         
  [26] "111"                                                       
  [27] "  Bettiol AlbertoEF Pro Cycling "                          
  [28] "26"                                                        
  [29] "EF Pro Cycling"                                            
  [30] "175"                                                       
  [31] "100"                                                       
  [32] "1:311:31"                                                  
  [33] "5"                                                         
  [34] "44"                                                        
  [35] "  Fuglsang JakobAstana Pro Team "
```

I want to create columns for the every 1-8 observations and tried several options but without success.

All suggestions to split observations from one column into multiple columns are welcome.

Comment: Show us what you tried and where your approach failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss your example data defined with the code, let's assume it is called `df`,
You could use matrix function and define number of columns.

```
t(matrix(ncol = 8, as.character(df[,1])) #to get variables in columns, you need to transpose the matrix with t() function.
```

You can subsequently transform it to data.frame with `as.data.frame`.